# Recover SVN repository data by adding empty revisions in place of missed revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Few SVN revisions got deleted and we are not able to checkout complete data from SVN repository .

We are using visual svn 3.4.6 version in Windows server and SVN data size is 900+ GB and its having almost 90000+ revisions.

How to find out missing revisions numbers and replace it with empty revision to recover the data.

please support to solve the issue, we are ready for paid service also

mail id- jinil.raman@excelindia.com
Mob-7907186802

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you do not have a backup, you are out of luck :( SVN does not provide any tools to repair broken revision files. Also, there is no SVN release 3.4.6, but I assume you are refering to the VisualSVN server version. For your problem, I fear it is not important.

Depending on the damage, you may can rescue most of the data inside but it is a long and tedious work:

1. identify the broken revisions
2. try to checkout subfolders before or after the broken revisions

**identify the broken revisions**

You should use

```
svnadmin verify <filepath_to_repo>
```

to check which revisions are broken. svnadmin will break on the first revision(starting at rev. 0)  which is broken. you then need to continue with

```
svnadmin verify --revision <broken_rev +1>  <filepath_to_repo>
```

**try to checkout subfolders before the broken revisions**

After having a collection of all bad revisions try to check out revisions before and in between these broken revisions. You may need to limit to subfolders to not encounter any errors. You should use

```
svn export <url_to_repo>
```

as it is faster than creating a working copy (you are not able to commit to the repo anyway)

Comment: FYI: `svnadmin verify` has the `--keep-going` option.